# Cannot open attached file with '#' sign in the filename. Firebug prompts 'NetworkError: 401 Unauthorized'

Tags: asp.net

Cannot open attached file with '#' sign in the filename. Firebug prompts 'NetworkError: 401 Unauthorized'

Comment: Yeah oke .... so what the question? You necessarily need to have a name with a # in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, you may not have property escaped the the hyper-link to the file. For example, if you use url such as "`www.xyz.com\file#name.txt`", because # has a special meaning (local anchors), browser will look for a file at  `www.xyz.com\file` and that would result in an error (typically 404). Suggest you to escape your urls (for example, %23 for # signe)